# Embedding 'Open Sans' font in svg - gstatic urls

Tags: svg, fonts

I need to embed the 'Open Sans' font in an svg. I found a [method that works](http://nimbupani.com/about-fonts-in-svg.html) but in order to use it with Google fonts, I plucked out the `src` listed in http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:

```
<defs>
  <style type='text/css'>
    <![CDATA[@font-face{font-family:'Open Sans';src:local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v9/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3ZBw1xU1rKptJj_0jans920.woff2) format('woff2'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v9/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3bO3LdcAZYWl9Si6vvxL-qU.woff) format('woff');}]]>
  </style>
</defs>
```

Should I be worried about the `gstatic` links moving over time, or are they truly "static"?

My concern is that `http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans` is static, but the links it resolves may actually expire and move.

Any other issues with this solution I should be aware of?

Comment: Why not embed the font data as a data uri?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other issue I encountered was the font owner may revise their font glyphs and woff files are updated silently (**WITHOUT** my knowledge). Hence all the nicely designed webpages *may* end up looking like it was haphazardly slapped together.

An easy solution is to host these fonts on your site or perhaps Amazon S3; I'd ignore the "*truly static*" claims because sites can be unreachable for a variety of reasons and it is out of your control.

Sidenote: *Open Sans" is designed by [Steve Matteson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Matteson), along with a few others like Liberation fonts, which is worth checking out.